# Why does Yarn 2 / Yarn 3 add `packageManager` to package.json, and can I delete it?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg-v2

After migrating to Yarn 2 / Yarn 3 (running `yarn version set stable`), yarn added a field to my package.json:

```json
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.3",
```

What is this field for? Can I safely delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `packageManager` field is a newer experimental feature of the package.json, [introduced in Node v16.9.0](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/all.html#all_packages_packagemanager).

While it's safe to remove, on systems that have [corepack](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/corepack.html) enabled, this can be a useful way to keep your package manager (yarn) in sync with other members of your development team.